# QMaemoListPickSelector not showing anything

Tags: c++, qt, maemo, n900

Alright I tried using a QMaemo5ListPickSelector together with a QMaemo5ValueButton, but when I click on the button, a popup dialog box does come up, but it doesnt any list ..

Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image]

This is the code I'm using to start up the above mentioned two components and to populate the lists:

```
QMaemo5ValueButton *x = new QMaemo5ValueButton("Testing .. !");
QStandardItemModel model (10,2);
int j,k;
for(j=0;j<=1;j++)
{
    k=0;
    for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
    {
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString("%0").arg(k));
        k+=5;
        model.setItem(i,j,item);
    }
}
x->setValueLayout(QMaemo5ValueButton::ValueBesideText);
QMaemo5ListPickSelector *sel = new QMaemo5ListPickSelector();
sel->setModel(&model);

x->setPickSelector(sel);
hbox->addWidget(x);
```

I would say I'm probably populating the list incorrectly ..